# Overfull hbox before producing SVG output

Tags: luatex, dvisvgm

My MWE still fools me. I have only these lines in the .tex file:

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}

%% debug overful hbox
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen%
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen%
% \showboxdepth=5
% \showboxbreadth=5
\setlength{\overfullrule}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (13.205,-11.662) {\fontsize{14}{14}SIDEREAL HOUR ANGLE};
  \node[font=\fontsize{12}{14}, anchor=east] at (26.410,-11.662) {\textcopyright\enspace 2021 Firstname Lastname};
  \node at (13.205,6.033) {\fontsize{12}{15}\textbf{LUNAR DISTANCE (SHA 290° to 120°)\quad06 Dec 2021}};
  \node[rotate=90,font=\fontsize{14}{16}] at (-1.251,0.0) {DECLINATION};
  \node[rotate=90,font=\fontsize{12}{14}] at (-1.251,-3.711) {South};
  \node[rotate=90,font=\fontsize{12}{14}] at (-1.251,3.711) {North};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I compile this with:

```
latex example.tex
dvisvgm example
```

and every time I get an Overfull hbox (I use a different filename):

[image]

and the SVG produced shows it on the right border:

[image]

- the "DISTANCE" is output as "DIST ANCE"
- the font sizes are incorrect (too small) except on the top line
- and something produces a huge "Overfull hbox"

I'm baffled as I have played with the few remaining lines and come to no conclusion. I use:

- Windows 10 (current)
- "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.10)"

Have I made an obvious mistake? Your assistance is much appreciated. Sorry, I find no "latex" tag.

**UPDATE 7th Dec:**

Using the following commands:

```
latex example.tex
dvisvgm example --font-format=woff
```

eliminates the space between "DIST ANCE"; the top line is now bold; font sizes of text appear correct. However the overfull hbox remains:

[image]

Lualatex requires to comment out `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}` and to replace the degrees symbol with `\textdegree`. Then execute:

```
dvilualatex example.tex
dvisvgm example --font-format=woff
```

The overfull hbox remains, which is depicted by the strong black bar on the right (which shouldn't be there!):

[image]

What is causing this massive overfull hbox?

**DISCOVERY 7th Dec:**

The huge Ovberfull hbox was being caused by the "minimal" class. Change the class to "standalone", as in `\documentclass[tikz,dvisvgm]{standalone}` and this problem disappears. See: https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en

However one problem still remains: text size is changed only when it is set to bold with `\textbf{....}`. Current test case:

```
\documentclass[tikz,dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[font=\fontsize{14}{15}] at (13.205,-11.662) {\textbf{SIDEREAL HOUR ANGLE}};
  \node[font=\fontsize{14}{15},anchor=east] at (26.410,-11.662) {\textcopyright\enspace 2021 Firstname Lastname};
  \node[font=\fontsize{14}{15}] at (13.205,6.033) {\textbf{LUNAR DISTANCE (SHA 290\textdegree to 120\textdegree)\quad06 Dec 2021}};
  \node[rotate=90,font=\fontsize{14}{15}] at (-1.251,0.0) {\textbf{DECLINATION}};
  \node[rotate=90,font=\fontsize{14}{15}] at (-1.251,-3.711) {\textbf{South}};
  \node[rotate=90,font=\fontsize{14}{15}] at (-1.251,3.711) {\textbf{North}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

but I have no control over the text size of the Copyright text. And if you change any bold text to normal (remove `\textbf{...}`), the text size flips back to some default size. Tips welcome!

Comment: The wrong character sizes and their spacing is probably a problem with your SVG viewer that can't render SVG fonts properly. Just call dvisvgm with option `-n` or `-fwoff` and this issue should go away.

Comment: Thanks. Much better now ... but I cannot find any reason for the huge Overfull hbox. NOTE: adding a ton of graphics into the middle works perfectly! I must get to the cause of the Overfull hbox somehow.

Comment: The `minimal` "class" (which shouldn't be used like this) gives you a text width of 6.5in or about 16.5cm. Then you are placing text at an x coordinate of `26.41cm` (plus 20pt paragraph indention + the width of the text), leading to placement way out of the textbox. That's what TeX is warning you about.

Comment: In order to apply the font size to the whole text, you need to group it with a font selection command, e.g. `\textrm` for the default font style. Otherwise, `\fontsize` doesn't take effect at the beginning of the text, as you can see when running `dviasm` on the DVI file. Instead of `\fontsize`, you could use TeX's font size modifiers (`\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE` etc.).

Comment: You might also want to add `{}` after `\textdegree` to prevent swallowing the following space. ;-)

Comment: @Martin, thanks x 2! I don't want to apply a font size to the whole text (there's more in the plot space). I used named fonts originally - I guess they came back with '-fwoff'. I require individual settings, which I guess become active whenever a font modifier is used (bold, italic, color,...) '\fontsize' is only in my MWE.

Comment: @Martin ... YES! Named font sizes work! It does change the Copyright text font size. (Amazing.) Now there's there's one more oddity when using tikzpicture, but I have to create a new question for this final topic.

Comment: @Aendie Great to hear that it works now. I didn't mean to set a global font size -- that was a bit misleading. If you want normal text to resize correctly when using `\fontsize`, you should surround the text with `\textrm` similar to `\textbf` in your examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marcel Krüger said in the comments, the `minimal` class should not be used when generating a Ti*k*Z picture on a single page because the page width and height are limited. I found this out the hard way. I wanted a diagram that fits on an A4 landscape page in a PDF file to go into a SVG file.

I found no list of classes, and in the MiKTeX folders there are 23 to choose from. So guesswork led me to try the `standalone` class (in the MiKTeX `tex\latex\standalone` subfolder). This solves the large `Overfull \hbox` problem I had. Details on this class are found here: https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en

The full diagram now looks correct (although the constellation lines are somewhat thinner than in the PDF):

[image]

Thanks to Martin also!